# How to avoid messes like `"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \2\)]\)"` when using the uploader

Tags: discussion

In conjunction with this answer [Superscripts and subscripts in graphics causes italics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/172847/12558) Carl Woll complained about the mess of  `"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \2\)]\)"`. This mess does not appear in my notebook but only when I have posted into Stackexchange using the uploader. Is there a way to avoid this sort of mess? I note that when I copy back into my notebook the mess stays. The suggestion to change to `RawInputForm` does not seem to help. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you use 2D typesetting *inside* of a string, you will get *linear syntax*. Here is an animation showing an example:

[image]

It is actually rather non-trivial to convert *linear syntax* into normal expressions. So, in my opinion, it is preferable to avoid using 2D typesetting inside of a string. Instead use [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row) or possibly [`StringForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringForm). For example:

```
Row[{"m ", s^2}]
StringForm["m `1`", s^2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this.  The use of `StringForm` is ingenious.  Only must avoid having a prior value for s!

Comment: @Hugh It seems that using `HoldForm[s^2]` avoids that problem (but I don't know if it causes others).